# How to find the probability that a random sample of 10 points out of 52 points of data will have a mean close to the total mean?

Tags: sampling, mean, finite-population

I have a data set that consists of 52 weeks of data. I want to find the probability that any 10 weeks of data within the set of 52 weeks is close to the mean of the total 52 weeks.

Close meaning whatever measure seems appropriate (whether it is within a standard deviation, or what have you).

I assume this is a fairly obvious problem, but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how you would get this.

Comment: I assume you mean "sample mean" $\bar{X}$ as opposed to the population mean?

Comment: @queenbee Right, the probability that the sample mean will be close to the same as the population mean.

Comment: I believe you mean the probability that the 10-week sample mean will be close to the 52-week sample mean.  Also, are data collected once per week?  And, to answer the question requires that one know the standard deviation within the entire 52-week sample.

Comment: If you mean $10$ *consecutive* weeks, why not just compute the $43$ means of all such periods and compare their distribution to the mean of all $52$ weeks?

Comment: @rolando2 Correct. Let's assume we also know the standard deviation of the entire 52-week sample.

Comment: @whuber Not consecutive weeks - any 10 weeks chosen at random although that is a good idea if it was consecutive weeks.

Comment: Are all of your data positive?

Comment: What are your population mean and variance?

Comment: 346 mean and 67600 variance

Comment: I'd define some criterion of 'close' and then use simulation. Simulation makes it easy to change criteria and see how much the answer changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the finite population were not relevant, the variance of the sample mean $\bar x$ would be $\sigma^2 /n = {67600 \over 10}.$ With the finite population correction factor, it becomes $$\sigma^2_{\bar x}={{{52-10} \over {52}}\left(6760\right)}=5460.$$

Then $\sigma =3.5187\sigma_{\bar x}.$ Using Chebyshev's inequality, the probability that $\bar x$ is more than $3.5187\sigma_{\bar x}$ away from the mean of 346 is less than ${{1 \over {3.5187^2}}}$, or about $0.0808$

Therefore the probability that $\bar x$ is within one standard deviation of the mean is at least $0.9192,$ where standard deviation is understood to be $\sqrt{67600}=260$ for this sentence.

As noted above, simulation could be used to get a tighter result.